# TCP Server to Client

Tags: c#, tcp, client

I have made a connection between server and client, the client send data to the server and receive a response, but i wanna send data from the server to client and receive the response from client to server, is it possible ? Here is my code :
[Client] :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Multi_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket
            (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            ConnectToServer();
            RequestLoop();
            Exit();
        }

        private static void ConnectToServer()
        {
            int attempts = 0;

            while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt " + attempts);
                    _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            _clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("C1"));
        }

        private static void RequestLoop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"<Type ""exit"" to properly disconnect client>");

            SendRequest();
            ReceiveResponse();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close socket and exit app
        /// </summary>
        private static void Exit()
        {
            SendString("exit"); // Tell the server we re exiting
            _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            _clientSocket.Close();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private static void SendRequest()
        {
            Console.Write("Send a request: ");
            string request = Console.ReadLine();
            SendString(request);

            if (request.ToLower() == "exit")
            {
                Exit();
                return;
            }
        }

        private static void SendString(string text)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            _clientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }

        private static void ReceiveResponse()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int received = _clientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);

            if (received == 0) return;

            byte[] data = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, data, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

[Server] :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using NetworkCommsDotNet;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static readonly int _BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[_BUFFER_SIZE];
        string text;
        Socket current;
        Socket test;
        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text += text + "\n";
            }
        }
        private void SetupServer()
        {
            SetText("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
            _serverSocket.Listen(5);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            SetText("Server Setup");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close all connected client (we do not need to shutdown the server socket as its connections
        /// are already closed with the clients)
        /// </summary>
        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in _clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            _serverSocket.Close();
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = null;

            try
            {
                socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
            {
                return;
            }

            _clientSockets.Add(socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            SetText("Client connected, waiting for request...");
            test = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }
        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = 0;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                SetText("Client forcefully disconnected");
                current.Close(); // Dont shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway
                _clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
            text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            SetText("Received Text: " + text);
            if (text.ToLower() == "get tim") // Client requested time
            {
                SetText("Text is a get time request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                current.Send(data);
                SetText("Time sent to client");
            }
            else if (text.ToString() == "C1") // Client wants to exit gracefully
            {
                SetText("Received :: C1");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                current.Send(data);
            }

            else
            {
                SetText("Server is sending invalid packet");
                SetText("Warning Sent");
            }
            current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), current);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetupServer();
        }
        private void Send_Received(string mess)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mess);
            test.Send(data);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseAllSockets();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Send_Received(textBox1.Text);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you've done and why it doesn't work.  The size of the code dump you've left is large enough that noone is likely to dive in and try to figure things out from what little you've writen.

Comment: Well, i am blocked, i don't have any idea on how to send data from server to client before the client send any data to server

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, it is possible.

Long aswer: Yes. Your current code is implemented this way:

- Server initializes and prepares to receive connections.
- Client tries to connect.
- Server accepts connection, adds to clientSockets collection.
- Client sends "C1".
- Server receives content, interprets, and send answer back.
- Client receives answer.

And then you enter a loop, since no other content is sent. You implemented a synchronous protocol - client talks, server talks back, client dumps it to console.

Let me suggest a quick implementation so you can test a server->client->server exchange:

- Implement an asynchronous timer on your server.
- After 10 seconds, if no incoming message arrives from an specific client, send a "PING?" message to it.
- Parse the incoming content on the client. If the message is equal to "PING?", answer with a "PONG!".

This is a very simple QoS protocol - you'll be testing the connection's health.

Let us know if you manage to implement it. =)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! I'm going to check all this and let you knew if it's resulted or not.

Comment: You are welcome: Async communications can be somewhat tricky to learn, but once you get a hold of it it's a great concept to keep in mind for  SaaS (System as a Service) solutions.

Comment: Actually, if no client have send a content to server, the Socket variable is null, so when the server send a data, it shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", And thank you again, you're great !

Comment: That is correct: You should only loop through your client connections collection if there's at least one member already added to it. =)

Comment: Okay, I'm going to test now, thank you so much :)
Edit : I connect a client, and i send data from the server, at the log text, it said that data are sent, but in console it doesn't show anything
Edit 2 : When i send data from console and the server respond, the text is on the console correctly.

Comment: Do you have any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i know where is the problem, when the server send something to the client and the client hasn't already sent something, the client doesn't show the thing until he sent another stuff :O
Example (i know it's complicated) :
Server sent C1 and show in the console C1 sent to client : Client do nothing (he should show in the console C1O)
Client sent Pa (random) and show in the console CAO : Server receive Pa
Client sent Ka (random) and show in the console (Invalid request because the server has received Pa so it sends invalid request text)
I hope that it's clean even if i knew that it's not :S

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by editing the RequestLoop function :

```
private static void RequestLoop()
    {
        ReceiveResponse();

    }
```

It`s all :)